# Extra monitors not detected after replugging in docking station

Tags: 16.04, unity, multiple-monitors, display, thinkpad

I am using **Lenovo P50 Thinkpad** with **2 extra monitors** in my office. I am using **Ubuntu 16.04** with **unity** display manager. When I go for meeting, I take my laptop along with me. When I come back and replug it. It ***does not detect extra 2 monitors until I restart it again***.

Does someone know how to make detectable ?

Comment: Do you get any error messages? And which graphics card does you computer have?

Comment: Just xorg gets crash. I am using Nvidia Quadro M1000, Lenovo Thinkpad P50. But I amusing ubuntu generic graphics card

Comment: Try using the propriety driver from Nvidia.